# Swap std::vector as function parameter

Tags: c++, stl, parameters, parameter-passing, stdvector

I would like to swap in an `std::vector` as a function parameter, so that the vector doesn't have to be copied.

Something like this:

```
function( std::vector< MyType >().swap( my_vector ) );
```

Or in my case like this:

```
std::make_pair( 0, std::vector< MyType >().swap( my_vector ) );
```

But of course `std::vector::swap` returns void, not the created vector.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: why don't you use a reference?

Comment: @perreal Because I don't have control over the function. (`std::make_pair`)

Comment: @Jay: If the function copies its argument, and you can't change the function, it is impossible to make the function not copy its argument. (Of course, in the case of `std::make_pair`, there is a version which takes its parameters by rvalue reference and which forwards them to the `pair` constructor, thus moving the argument rather than copying it (if the argument is an rvalue reference))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use any modern compiler, then you can use `std::move`, which takes your vector and returns it as an rvalue:

```
function(std::move(my_vector));
```

If that's not available to you, you could try something like this:

```
template<typename T>
T Move(T & val)
{
    T ret;
    ret.swap(val);
    return ret;
}
```

Let me know if you have any luck with that.

Or, you can swap the vector directly into the pair after its creation:

```
std::pair<int, std::vector<MyType> > p;
p.second.swap(my_vector);
```

Though, I guess this won't help you if you need the return value of `std::make_pair` as an rvalue.

Comment: I had trouble setting up C++11x in my environment, so I wasn't able to test `std::move`, but I am sure it would work well. Thanks.